# How to reinstate a removed user from team in GitHub without consuming pending invite?

Tags: github

How to reinstate a removed user from team in GitHub without consuming pending invite?

I am a user in GitHub with owner access on a team.
By-mistake removed a member who had accepted the invitation to join the team.
Now when i try to reinstate the removed member i get option to invite the member again but it consumes my pending invitation access which i want to use to invite other members?
How can i reinstate the removed member without consuming my pending invitation access?

Answer (score 0):

Only [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/) would be able to sort this out.

By default, reinstating your removed user would mean re-inviting it again, which does indeed consume an invitation access, as illustrated by the [GitHub API repository Invitation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#invitations).

From "[Add a repository collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#add-a-repository-collaborator)"

> To prevent abuse, you are limited to sending 50 invitations to a repository per 24 hour period.
> Note there is no limit if you are inviting organization members to an organization repository.

So waiting 24 hours would be enough to repeat the invitation.